# Java: Handling infrequent incoming packets in a UDP application

Tags: java, client, server

I am writing a client-server application where the client sends messages to the server every 5 seconds or so and the server responds quite infrequently. How do I handle this on the client side because the client can not remain stuck at the ".receive()" blocking call

Comment: How about session-less connection? Like http session. Client opens connection, send data, closes connection.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the application is in UDP.
Is thread.interrupt() any good for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

How heavy duty are the client/server?

Light: use threads to make it non blocking

Heavy: You could implement a messaging architecture such as RabbitMQ